# The vector aiming to enemy is in wrong direction

Tags: physics, vector, python

In a 2d game, I am trying to shoot at a moving enemy and the vehicle that is shooting is also moving. However, the velocity of the bullet is not in the same direction as the position of the enemy. The bullet starting position is the position of the vehicle.

**My Code**

```
bullet_enemy_vec = self.world.enemy[0].pos - self.vel
        bullet_enemy_vec_new = self.vel + bullet_enemy_vec
        self.vel = bullet_enemy_vec_new
        self.vel.normalise()
        self.vel = self.vel * self.speed
```

Comment: You're getting `bullet_enemy_vec_new` by starting with the enemy position, subtracting your velocity, then adding your velocity again, which cancels out to a no-op. Did you mean to subtract your *position* in order to get the displacement vector pointing to the enemy from where you are?

Comment: yes, I want to get a velocity in the direction of the enemy

Comment: @DMGregory this is what I implemented https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333350/moving-point-along-the-vector

Comment: No, you did not implement that. Read the variables carefully. You used velocity where that answer uses position. These vectors are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract position, not velocity.

```
self.vel = self.world.enemy[0].pos - self.pos
self.vel.normalise()
self.vel = self.vel * self.speed
```